# Javascript -- Prey project -- Os: does not exist

Tags: node.js, javascript

I'd been using Prey Project on and off for years, and I just realized it wasn't working.  So I'm trying to re-initialize my setup ...

Since I'm running Slackware and not Ubuntu, it refuses to run:

```
  PREY 1.9.6 spreads its wings!
  Current time: Thu Nov 26 2020 13:03:37 GMT-0500 (EST)
  Running with PID 31853 as prey over Node.js v8.9.1 on a x64 linux system (14.2)
[...]
     info Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:38 GMT [reports] Report gathered: specs
    error Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:44 GMT [control-panel] Unable to register device: 
Os:  does not exist.
    error Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:44 GMT Error: 
Os:  does not exist.
     info Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:44 GMT 1 plugins loaded with 1 errors.
 critical Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:44 GMT UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: 
Os:  does not exist.
     info Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:03:44 GMT Gracefully shutting down. Will self-destruct in 5 secs.
```

I don't know any JavaScript, so I'm not sure where to turn to address this.  I guess the best option is to find what process is generating the `Os:  does not exist` error and force it to return any kind of successful response.

Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: have you asked Prey?

Comment: "We only provide official Linux support for Ubuntu systems. "